# Scheduling Events For EDT From Different Classes Possible?

Tags: java, user-interface, event-handling

So after some research I'm realizing that all GUI related events should be handled on EDT. Is there any way you can sequentially organize actions from different classes? I know if in the same class you can explicitly do one thing before the next. All input is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I suggest making a new class and call it Calling or something along the line of having to call methods from all of your classes, then make your main method and have that call everything you need from there, in sequential order.
aka:

```
public class Calling {

    public void main(String[] args) {
        main.start();
        class.method();
        //and so on
    }
}
```

and change your old main method to start, and take out all of the call methods from there and move them here after you call start.